# Collecting links from a JS-Based Webpage using Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to collect all links from a webpage as seen below (25 links from each 206 pages, around 5200 total links), which also has a load more news button (as three dots). I wrote my script, but my script does not give any links that I tried to collect.  I updated some of Selenium attributes. I really don't know why I could not get all the links.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


from selenium.webdriver import Chrome


#Initialize the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()


driver.get("https://www.mfa.gov.tr/sub.en.mfa?ad9093da-8e71-4678-a1b6-05f297baadc4")


page_count = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='rgInfoPart']")
text = page_count.text
page_count = int(text.split()[-1])


links = []


for i in range(1, page_count + 1):
    # Click on the page number
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//a[text()='{i}']").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    # Wait for the page to load
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    # Extract the links from the page
    page_links = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'sub_lstitm'})
    for link in page_links:
        links.append("https://www.mfa.gov.tr"+link.find('a')['href'])
    time.sleep(5)

driver.quit()

print(links)
```

I tried to run my code but actually I couldn't. I need to have some solution for this.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using beautifulsoup? I ask because it seems like you can do everything with selenium only

Comment: sometimes, it becomes handy to locate selectors for me with bs4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do everything in Selenium using the following method:

1. Wait for the links to be visible on the page
2. Get titles and urls
3. Get the current page number
4. If there is the button for the next page, then click it and repeat from step 1., otherwise it means we are in the last page hence the execution ends

What follows is the complete code to scrape all 206 pages

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.mfa.gov.tr/sub.en.mfa?ad9093da-8e71-4678-a1b6-05f297baadc4")

titles, urls = [], []

while 1:
    print('current page:', driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td span').text, end='\r')
    
    links = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.sub_lstitm a")))
    for link in links:
        titles.append( link.text )
        urls.append( link.get_attribute('href') )
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//td//span/parent::td/following-sibling::td[1]').click()
    except:
        print('next page button not found')
        break

for i in range(len(titles)):
    print(titles[i],'\n',urls[i],'\n')
```

Comment: Dear sound wave, thank you so much for the answer. Actually, it partly worked because the window closes down after scrapping a couple of pages. Indeed, I need all 206 pages. The output console does not give any error.

Comment: This is the code I am using:

Comment: I also added "driver = webdriver.Chrome()" line at the beginning of my code.

Comment: I realized that it closes the page when it comes to three dots at the end of the page enumeration. It cannot load "load more" thing.

Comment: @kutsalzamazingo I added new code to solve that problem, check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Using only [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) you can easily collect all links from the [webpage](https://www.mfa.gov.tr/sub.en.mfa?ad9093da-8e71-4678-a1b6-05f297baadc4) inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.mfa.gov.tr/sub.en.mfa?ad9093da-8e71-4678-a1b6-05f297baadc4')
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.sub_lstitm > a")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.mfa.gov.tr/sub.en.mfa?ad9093da-8e71-4678-a1b6-05f297baadc4')
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sub_lstitm']/a")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['https://www.mfa.gov.tr/no_-17_-turkiye-ve-yemen-arasinda-gerceklestirilecek-konsolosluk-istisareleri-hk.en.mfa', 'https://www.mfa.gov.tr/no_-16_-sayin-bakanimizin-abd-ziyareti-hk.en.mfa', 'https://www.mfa.gov.tr/no_-15_-iran-islam-cumhuriyeti-disisleri-bakani-huseyin-emir-abdullahiyan-in-ulkemize-yapacagi-ziyaret-hk.en.mfa', 'https://www.mfa.gov.tr/no_-14_-nepal-de-meydana-gelen-ucak-kazasi-hk.en.mfa', 'https://www.mfa.gov.tr/no_-13_-bosna-hersek-bakanlar-konseyi-baskan-yrd-ve-disisleri-bakani-bisera-turkovic-in-ulkemizi-ziyareti-hk.en.mfa', 'https://www.mfa.gov.tr/no_-12_-turkiye-iran-konsolosluk-istisareleri-hk.en.mfa', 'https://www.mfa.gov.tr/no_-11_-kuzey-kibris-turk-cumhuriyeti-kurucu-cumhurbaskani-sayin-rauf-raif-denktas-in-vefatinin-on-birinci-yildonumu-hk.en.mfa', 'https://www.mfa.gov.tr/no_-10_-italya-basbakan-yardimcisi-ve-disisleri-ve-uluslararasi-isbirligi-bakani-antonio-tajani-nin-ulkemizi-ziyareti-hk.en.mfa', 'https://www.mfa.gov.tr/no_-9_-kirim-tatar-soydaslarimiz-hakkinda-mahkumiyet-karari-verilmesi-hk.en.mfa', 'https://www.mfa.gov.tr/no_-8_-kuzeybati-suriye-ye-yonelik-bm-sinir-otesi-insani-yardim-mekanizmasinin-uzatilmasi-hk.en.mfa', 'https://www.mfa.gov.tr/no_-7_-brezilya-da-devlet-baskani-lula-da-silva-hukumeti-ni-ve-demokratik-kurumlari-hedef-alan-siddet-olaylari-hk.en.mfa', 'https://www.mfa.gov.tr/no_-6_-sudan-daki-gelismeler-hk.en.mfa', 'https://www.mfa.gov.tr/no_-5_-senegal-in-gniby-kentinde-meydana-gelen-kaza-hk.en.mfa', 'https://www.mfa.gov.tr/no_-4_-sayin-bakanimizin-afrika-ziyareti-hk.en.mfa', 'https://www.mfa.gov.tr/no_-3_-deas-teror-orgutu-ile-iltisakli-bir-sebekenin-malvarliklarinin-abd-makamlari-ile-eszamanli-olarak-dondurulmasi-hk.en.mfa', 'https://www.mfa.gov.tr/no_-2_-somali-de-meydana-gelen-teror-saldirisi-hk.en.mfa', 'https://www.mfa.gov.tr/no_-1_-israil-ulusal-guvenlik-bakani-itamar-ben-gvir-in-mescid-i-aksa-ya-baskini--hk.en.mfa', 'https://www.mfa.gov.tr/no_-386_-sayin-bakanimizin-brezilya-yi-ziyareti-hk.en.mfa', 'https://www.mfa.gov.tr/sc_-32_-gkry-nin-dogu-akdeniz-de-devam-eden-hidrokarbon-faaliyetleri-hk-sc.en.mfa', 'https://www.mfa.gov.tr/no_-385_-afganistan-da-yuksekogretimde-kiz-ogrencilere-getirilen-egitim-yasagi-hk.en.mfa', 'https://www.mfa.gov.tr/no_-384_-isvec-disisleri-bakani-tobias-billstrom-un-turkiye-yi-ziyareti-hk.en.mfa', 'https://www.mfa.gov.tr/no_-383_-yemen-cumhuriyeti-disisleri-ve-yurtdisindaki-yemenliler-bakani-dr-ahmed-awad-binmubarak-in-ulkemizi-ziyareti-hk.en.mfa', 'https://www.mfa.gov.tr/no_-382_-gambiya-disisleri-uluslararasi-isbirligi-ve-yurtdisindaki-gambiyalilar-bakani-nin-ulkemizi-ziyareti-hk.en.mfa', 'https://www.mfa.gov.tr/no_-381_-bosna-hersek-e-ab-adaylik-statusu-verilmesi-hk.en.mfa', 'https://www.mfa.gov.tr/no_-380_-turkiye-meksika-ust-duzey-iki-uluslu-komisyonu-siyasi-komitesinin-ikinci-toplantisinin-duzenlenmesi-hk.en.mfa']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Dear undetected selenium, thank you so much. But, this gave me only links from the first page.

Comment: @kutsalzamazingo This answer was based on the requirement to scrap the first page. No doubt you got the idea now. You can implement the pagination easily.

Comment: I couldn't handle actually.

Comment: @kutsalzamazingo get your hands dirty with some code. We are here to guide you :)